# unable to rename the excel file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am copying the contents from one excel to another excel and deleting the source excel sheet. After deleting the source excel sheet, I am renaming that file to original name. However, replace is not working. Not sure, where am I doing wrong. Here is the code.

```
 'getting the file
 filePath = BrowseForFile() 
 Const xlUp = -4162
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 fileName = Mid(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\") + 1)
 MsgBox "filepath is --->" & filepath
 MsgBox "selected filename is --->" & fileName
 newPath = CStr(Left(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\")))
 MsgBox "newpath is --->" & newPath
 newname = newPath & "temp_" & fileName
 MsgBox "new file name is i.e., newname ----->" & newname

 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add 

 objWorkbook.SaveAs(newname)  

 Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
 Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open(newname)
 objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
 objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial -4163
 objWorkbook1.save
 objWorkbook2.save
 objWorkbook1.close
 objWorkbook2.close

 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 if objFSO.FileExists(filePath) Then  
   MsgBox "inside delete file condition"
   objFSO.DeleteFile filePath
 else
   MsgBox "No file"
 End If

 MsgBox "newname filename before renaming it--------" & newname  

 ' renaming the file to original
 newfileName = Replace(newname, "temp_","")

 MsgBox "file after renaming is i.e., newfileName ------>" &   newfileName
 MsgBox "fileName is i.e., fileName-------------->" & fileName

 MsgBox "fileName for final processing is ------>" & newfileName

 WScript.Sleep 10000  
 Set objWorkbook3= objExcel.Workbooks.Open(newfileName)  
 Set ThisSheet = objWorkbook3.ActiveSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the new file as “temp1” or whatever you prefer, close then delete the original, then rename the “temp1” to the name you want.

Comment: newname = newPath & "temp_" & filename

Comment: Well, do you delete the file itself or the path? You have a variable filename as well as filepath...

Comment: deleting the file,  filePath gives the filename including filepath, where as filename gives only the filename.

Comment: Hi, I have made a workaround. I used copyFile command for renaming and deleted the temp_ file.